# How can we get the count of number of weeks in a month in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

Using below query i can get the current week.

```
select extract(week from current_timestamp)
```

I am trying to get how many weeks we have for a given month.

Comment: There are always 4 full weeks in a given month. What else you want to know? no of particular day? like how many saturdays or sundays?

Comment: @AnkitBajpai Not only full weeks, we want to count even if one or two days of next month falls into current month weeks

Comment: What is your expected output then?

Comment: With partials there could be up to 6 weeks per year (see Jan 2022). But making that determination you need to define a week. You have not done that, so what do you consider a week.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe this will be a final solution to you but it might help.

`TO_NUMBER` function is used so we can add numbers in the outer select and the result of the to_char function is not number :)

`TO_CHAR` function is used so we can get number of the month from the date we have "calculated" with the date_trunc function. The result of the TO_CHAR function will be 05 for the first month.

`DATE_TRUNC` function in combination with `+ interval '1 month - 1 day'` was used to get the first day of the current month and then with this part `+ interval '1 month - 1 day'` we get the last date of the month in this format: `2020-01-31 00:00:00+00`. And from that date we will get value `05`(number of the week) with to_char function.

I have calculated 1st and 12th here for you:

```
SELECT one "1st"
       , "12th" 
from (
select 
(to_number(to_char((date_trunc('month', CURRENT_DATE) + interval '1 month - 1 day'), 'IW'), '99')  
- to_number(to_char((date_trunc('month', CURRENT_DATE)), 'IW'), '99') +1) "one",
(to_number(to_char((date_trunc('month', CURRENT_DATE) + interval '12 month - 1 day'), 'IW'), '99')
- to_number(to_char((date_trunc('month', CURRENT_DATE) + interval '11 month'), 'IW'), '99') +1) "12th") table_alias
```

Here is a [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=b482dbc3bf8866b229646e4d3781d60c)

Comment: Hi @user8545255, would appreciate a feedback from you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To know the number of weeks that overlap with a month, try

```
SELECT date_part('week', date_trunc('month', current_timestamp) + INTERVAL '1 month' - INTERVAL '1 day')
     - date_part('week', date_trunc('month', current_timestamp))
     +1;
```

This calculates the difference between the week of the last day and the week of the first day in a month, then adds. one.

Replace `current_timestamp` with a timestamp in the month you are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

You may be much better off just looking this up on a calendar and storing the results on a table that your code can lookup later. 
First note that if partial weeks are considered then OP is not requesting "how many weeks are in the month" but "how many weeks is the month in". While a subtle difference but still a difference. 
The result being that all months are in 5 or 6 weeks, except Feb which has 4 or 5. 
While the attempts by @Laurenz Albe and @VBoke are admirable both doomed suffering the same Achilles heel; the disparency between ISO-8601 standard and the Gregorian calendar. The standard is well defined and consistent unfortunately the calendar doesn't conform to to the standard.  
The standard defines each week to begin on Monday and exactly 7 days long, calendar months not so regular. Further the standard only recognizes one significant date - 4-Jan. That date is **always** in the week 1 of the year. As a result the week for 1-Jan may be week 52/53 of the previous year and last days of Dec may fall into week 1 of the following year. This can result a negative week  calculation. Finally, at least now, is the fact any month beginning on Sun this algorithm generates an additional week. OH and then there is Feb.  
Using Laurenz's as a base line example:

```
    -- expanded to show Month Year, start and end week number and the number of weeks
    set timezone to 'UTC'; 
    with date_list (a_date) as (select generate_series('2019-12-01'::timestamptz,'2030-02-01'::timestamptz,interval '1 month')) 
    select to_char(a_date, 'Mon yyyy')
         , date_part('week', date_trunc('month', a_date) + INTERVAL '1 month' - INTERVAL '1 day') end_of_month_week
         , date_part('week', date_trunc('month', a_date))                                         start_of_month_week
         -- L actual
         , date_part('week', date_trunc('month', a_date) + INTERVAL '1 month' - INTERVAL '1 day')
           - date_part('week', date_trunc('month',a_date)) + 1                                    number_of_weeks_month_in    
              from date_list
    ;
```

Seems correct in the majority of cases but obviously not all. Taking into account the above I modify Laurenz's maintaining the essential except for the adjustments. Resulting in:

```
set timezone to 'UTC'; 
with date_list (a_date) as (select generate_series('2019-12-01'::timestamptz,'2030-02-01'::timestamptz,interval '1 month')) 
select a_date, start_of_month_week, end_of_month_week
     , case when start_of_month_week > end_of_month_week
            then case when date_part('month', a_date) = 1  
                      -- adjustment for Jan
                      then case when date_part('dow', a_date) = 0
                                then 5 else 6 end
                      -- adjustment for Dec
                      else case when date_part('dow',a_date) = 6
                                then 6 else 5 end
                      end
             when date_part('month',a_date) = 2
             -- and then there is Feb
                  then case when date_part('day', a_date+interval '1 month - 1 day') = 29
                            then 5

                            when date_part('dow', a_date) = 0
                            then 4 else 5
                        end   
             when date_part('dow', a_date) = 0
                  -- month beging on Sun
                  then end_of_month_week - start_of_month_week
            -- No adjustment needed Mar - Nov And Not 1st on Mon
            else end_of_month_week - start_of_month_week + 1
       end::integer  number_of_weeks_month_in
       , date_part('day', a_date+interval '1 month - 1 day') 
  from ( 
        SELECT a_date::date
             , date_part('week', date_trunc('month', a_date) + INTERVAL '1 month' - INTERVAL '1 day') end_of_month_week
             , date_part('week', date_trunc('month', a_date))                                         start_of_month_week
          from date_list
       ) dts  
      ;
```

Disclaimer: While I believe the adjusted query is correct, but I have NOT investigated each month and validated each month nor other days of the week that may require their own adjustment to the base algorithm. Repeating it may be easier to look up those values and store them in a table.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    mnth
    , DATE(DATE_TRUNC('week', mnth)) AS week_start
    , DATE(DATE_TRUNC('week', mnth + INTERVAL '1 month' - INTERVAL '1 day')) AS week_end
    , (DATE(DATE_TRUNC('week', mnth + INTERVAL '1 month' - INTERVAL '1 day')) - DATE(DATE_TRUNC('week', mnth))) / 7 + 1 AS week_cnt
FROM
    (VALUES ('2022-01-01'::date)) AS a (mnth)
;
```

Result:

```
    mnth    | week_start |  week_end  | week_cnt
------------+------------+------------+----------
 2022-01-01 | 2021-12-27 | 2022-01-31 |        6
```